# Cannot build the select query which requires group by

Tags: sql

I have a table of employees. The schema is something like below:

```
Columns: name varchar
         status varchar
         id varchar
```

The status could be anything from "online", "offline", "away", "busy". This table captures status of all employees at certain time, periodically.

Sample input:

```
Frank "online"
Toby "away"
Frank "busy"
Alice "offline"
Alex "away"
Toby "online"
```

I have to create a report as below:

```
ALex "not available"
Alice "not available"
Frank "busy"
Toby "available"
```

Basically the condition is that an employee will be shown as "busy", if he/she has been busy at least once, "available", if he/she has been "online" at least once and never "busy", and "not available" if he/she has never been "online" or "busy".

How to write such a query. I am absolutely a noob in SQL. Please help me.

Regards.

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) show us sample data and desired output

Comment: Different databases vendors implement different functionality and use different syntax.  So, do you use MySQL5.x MySQL8, Oracle, SQLite, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean you can use next query:

```
SELECT 
    `name`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `statuses` LIKE '%busy%' THEN 'busy'
        WHEN `statuses` LIKE '%online%' AND `statuses` NOT LIKE '%busy%'   THEN 'available'
        WHEN `statuses` NOT LIKE '%online%' AND `statuses` NOT LIKE '%busy%'   THEN 'not available'
    END `status`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `name`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`status`) `statuses`
    FROM eployees GROUP BY `name`
) emploees_statuses;
```

[Test SQL query here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=1a7034e9dc2b120fc1ffe32ce57461dd&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

MSSQL use `STRING_AGG` instead `GROUP_CONCAT`;

```
SELECT 
    name,
    CASE 
        WHEN statuses LIKE '%busy%' THEN 'busy'
        WHEN statuses LIKE '%online%' AND statuses NOT LIKE '%busy%'   THEN 'available'
        WHEN statuses NOT LIKE '%online%' AND statuses NOT LIKE '%busy%'   THEN 'not available'
    END status
FROM (
SELECT 
    name, 
    STRING_AGG(status, ',') statuses
FROM eployees GROUP BY name
) emploees_statuses;
```

[MSSQL STRING_AGG online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=81e9fb30f46d5ba1ef4345403d5d2ac5&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

Comment: `AND statuses NOT LIKE '%busy%'` is redundant, as all rows containing `'busy'` will have already been caught by the first line of the `CASE` expression.  Similarly, the final line doesn't need any conditions and can be `ELSE` *(assuming statuses is not nullable)*.

Comment: @MatBailie, sure, I just wrote sample query, you can improve it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your post, can't you just do :

```
    INSERT INTO ONLINE_EMPLOYEE 
    (SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE STATUS = 'ONLINE');
```

And then repeat on the other status ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following...

1. Translate the statuses to integers

- `0` = `'busy'`
- `1` = `'online'`
- NULL for the rest (to be otherwise ignored)

2. The the minimum of all those integer states

- If they've ever been `'busy'` the minimum would be `0`
- Else, if they've ever been `'online'` the minimum would be `1`
- Else, the minimum would be `NULL`

3. Recode the integer values in to strings

- `0` = `'busy'`
- `1` = `'available'`
- Else, `'not available'`

For example...

```
SELECT
  name,
  CASE
    MIN(
      CASE status
        WHEN 'busy'   THEN 0
        WHEN 'online' THEN 1
      END
    )
    WHEN 0 THEN 'busy'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'available'
           ELSE 'not available' END  AS status
FROM
  employees
GROUP BY
  name
```

This should also work in all SQL dialects.